# Program abruptly stops based on the length of an arbitrary word

Tags: python, break

I am trying to create a hangman game. My program abruptly stops based on the length of the set of a random word chosen. It should only stop once you guess the word or you reach the maxinum number of guesses.

```
#Krish Patel

from random import randrange


def load_words():
    word_list = ["mom"] #"apple","tomato","krish","name","pediatrician"]
    return word_list

words_dict = load_words()

def get_word():
    word=words_dict[randrange(0,len(words_dict))]
    return word

secret_word = get_word()
letters_guessed = set()
local_guesses= 0
max_guesses = 6
num_correct_letters = 0

def play_hangman():
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    global max_guesses
    global num_correct_letters
    global local_guesses

    print("Hello there! You are about to play a game of hangman!. Enjoy...")
    while not word_guessed() and  num_correct_letters != len(set(secret_word)) and local_guesses < max_guesses:
        guess = input("Enter a letter: ")
        if letters_guessed.add(guess) != letters_guessed:   
            local_guesses += 1
            letters_guessed.add(guess)
        else:
            print("You already guessed that letter!")
        print_guessed()
        word_guessed()
    if word_guessed() == True:
        print("You have won! The secret word was: " + secret_word)
        secret_word = get_word()
        letters_guessed = set()
        local_guesses= 0
        max_guesses = 6
        num_correct_letters = 0
    if local_guesses >= max_guesses:
        print("You went over your maximum number of allotted guesses. The secret word was: " + secret_word)
        secret_word = get_word()
        letters_guessed = set()
        local_guesses= 0
        max_guesses = 6
        num_correct_letters = 0

def print_guessed():
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    print("Your guesses are " + str(letters_guessed))

def word_guessed():
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    global num_correct_letters


    for i in set(secret_word):
        if i in letters_guessed:
            num_correct_letters += 1
    return num_correct_letters == len(set(secret_word))
```

What should happen is that you have 6 guesses to figure out the word is mom, but the program ends after two tries.

Comment: What are you expecting `if letters_guessed.add(guess) != letters_guessed:` to do? `add()` modifies the set and returns `None`, so the test will always succeed.

Comment: If you want to know if they already guessed the letter, use `if guess in letters_guessed:`.

Comment: Good luck guessing pediatrician in only 6 guesses, it has 9 different letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `word_guessed` you don't reset `num_correct_letters` back to `0` before counting the number of correct letters. So once you guess a single correct letter, this counter keeps increasing even though you don't guess other letters correctly. If it reaches `len(set(secret_word))`, the loop ends.

There's no need to check `num_correct_letters` in your `while` condition, since `word_guessed()` already checks it.

You don't need the loop in `word_guessed`, and yo don't need the variable `num_correct_letters`, you can simply write:

```
def word_guessed():
    global secret_word
    global letters_guessed
    return set(secret_word).issubset(letters_guessed)
```

You're also not testing whether `guess` is already in `letters_guessed` correctly. Use `guess not in letters_guessed`.

You should initialize all the variables once at the beginning of the function, rather than repeating that in both of the `if` statements at the end. And there's no need for them to be global variables, just pass them as function parameters.

```
from random import randrange

def load_words():
    word_list = ["mom","apple","tomato","krish","name","pediatrician"]
    return word_list

words_dict = load_words()

def get_word():
    word=words_dict[randrange(0,len(words_dict))]
    return word

def play_hangman():
    secret_word = get_word()
    letters_guessed = set()
    local_guesses= 0
    max_guesses = 6

    print("Hello there! You are about to play a game of hangman!. Enjoy...")
    while not word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed) and local_guesses < max_guesses:
        guess = input("Enter a letter: ")
        if guess not in letters_guessed:
            letters_guessed.add(guess)
            local_guesses += 1
            letters_guessed.add(guess)
        else:
            print("You already guessed that letter!")
        print_guessed(letters_guessed)
    if word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
        print("You have won! The secret word was: " + secret_word)
    elif local_guesses >= max_guesses:
        print("You went over your maximum number of allotted guesses. The secret word was: " + secret_word)

def print_guessed(letters_guessed):
    print("Your guesses are " + str(letters_guessed))

def word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    return set(secret_word).issubset(letters_guessed)

play_hangman()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I never even knew about the issubset command in python!

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of `set` to see all the operations that are available?